# I can not include glib in header file, but I can include in source file with Raspberry Pi

Tags: c, cmake, raspberry-pi, raspbian, glib

Currently, I am working with Raspberry Pi:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 8.0 (jessie)
Release:    8.0
Codename:   jessie
```

I have some libraries `(C language)` that look like bellow:

```
my_app\-my_app.c
      \ - CMakeLists.txt
      \-lib
         \-lib1\- CMakeLists.txt
              \- src
                 \- lib1.c
                 \- CMakeLists.txt 
              \- include 
                 \- lib1.h 
              \- cmake
                    \- modules
                        \- FindGLIB2.cmake 
                        \- MacroOutOfSourceBuild.cmake
....................
```

The `lib1` is depends on `glib`

```
#include <glib.h>
```

Here's my `CMakeLists.txt` for `my_app`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(my_app)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${my_app_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/modules ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})

# Enable C11 or at least C99
include(CheckCCompilerFlag)
CHECK_C_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c11" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_C11)
CHECK_C_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c99" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_C99)
if(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_C11)
    message(STATUS "Using C11.")
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -std=c11")
elseif(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_C99)
    message(STATUS "The compiler ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} has no C11 support. Using C99 instead.")
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -std=c99")
else()
    message(STATUS "The compiler ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} has no C11 nor C99 support. Please update your C compiler.")
endif()

SET (CMAKE_C_FLAGS                "-lm")
include(MacroOutOfSourceBuild)
include(TargetDistclean)

macro_ensure_out_of_source_build("${PROJECT_NAME} requires an out of source build.")


add_subdirectory(lib/lib2)
add_subdirectory(lib/lib1)


include_directories(${lib2_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
include_directories(${lib1_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

# Add sources
set(my_app_SOURCES my_app.c)

add_executable(my_app ${my_app_SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(my_app
                    lib2
                    lib1
)

install(TARGETS my_app
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
)
```

Here's my `CMakeLists.txt` for `my_app/lib1`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(lib1)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${lib1_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/modules ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})

SET (CMAKE_C_FLAGS                "")
include(MacroOutOfSourceBuild)

macro_ensure_out_of_source_build("${PROJECT_NAME} requires an out of source build.")

add_subdirectory(src)

install(DIRECTORY include/lib1 DESTINATION include)
```

Here's my `CMakeLists.txt` for `my_app/lib1/src`

```
# Include the directory itself as a path to include directories
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

include(FindGLIB2)

include_directories(
    ${lib1_SOURCE_DIR}/include
    ${GLIB2_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

set(lib1_SOURCES
lib1.c
)

add_library(lib1 ${lib1_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(lib1
                    ${GLIB2_LIBRARIES}
)

install(TARGETS lib1 
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
)
```

Here is the log file:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/my_app/build $ cmake ..
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.28") 
-- checking for one of the modules 'glib-2.0'
-- Found GLib2: glib-2.0 /usr/include/glib-2.0;/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/glib-2.0/include
-- Looking for include file glib/gregex.h
-- Looking for include file glib/gregex.h - not found
-- Looking for include file glib/gchecksum.h
-- Looking for include file glib/gchecksum.h - not found
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/pi/my_app/build
```

That means I already have `glib` on my system.

Now, I have this problems:
If I use `#include <glib.h>` only for `lib1.c`. Everything is OK.

If I use `#include <glib.h>` only for `lib1.h`. I saw this problem with `lib1.h`:

```
lib1.h:2:18: fatal error: glib.h: No such file or directory
 #include <glib.h>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
```

**EDITED**

The error come from `my_app.c` which include `lib1.h`

Here are more log with `VERBOSE=yes`

ERROR with `lib1.h`

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/my_app/build $ make VERBOSE=1
/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/pi/my_app -B/home/pi/my_app/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/pi/my_app/build/CMakeFiles /home/pi/my_app/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
make -f lib/bzle/src/CMakeFiles/bzle.dir/build.make lib/bzle/src/CMakeFiles/bzle.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
cd /home/pi/my_app/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/pi/my_app /home/pi/my_app/lib/bzle/src /home/pi/my_app/build /home/pi/my_app/build/lib/bzle/src /home/pi/my_app/build/lib/bzle/src/CMakeFiles/bzle.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
make -f lib/bzle/src/CMakeFiles/bzle.dir/build.make lib/bzle/src/CMakeFiles/bzle.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'lib/bzle/src/CMakeFiles/bzle.dir/build'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/pi/my_app/build/CMakeFiles  3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
[ 60%] Built target bzle
make -f lib/lib1/src/CMakeFiles/lib1.dir/build.make lib/lib1/src/CMakeFiles/lib1.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
cd /home/pi/my_app/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/pi/my_app /home/pi/my_app/lib/lib1/src /home/pi/my_app/build /home/pi/my_app/build/lib/lib1/src /home/pi/my_app/build/lib/lib1/src/CMakeFiles/lib1.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
make -f lib/lib1/src/CMakeFiles/lib1.dir/build.make lib/lib1/src/CMakeFiles/lib1.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'lib/lib1/src/CMakeFiles/lib1.dir/build'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/pi/my_app/build/CMakeFiles  1 2
[ 70%] Built target lib1
make -f lib/lib2/src/CMakeFiles/lib2.dir/build.make lib/lib2/src/CMakeFiles/lib2.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
cd /home/pi/my_app/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/pi/my_app /home/pi/my_app/lib/lib2/src /home/pi/my_app/build /home/pi/my_app/build/lib/lib2/src /home/pi/my_app/build/lib/lib2/src/CMakeFiles/lib2.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
make -f lib/lib2/src/CMakeFiles/lib2.dir/build.make lib/lib2/src/CMakeFiles/lib2.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'lib/lib2/src/CMakeFiles/lib2.dir/build'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/pi/my_app/build/CMakeFiles  20
[ 75%] Built target lib2
make -f lib/ini/src/CMakeFiles/ini.dir/build.make lib/ini/src/CMakeFiles/ini.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
cd /home/pi/my_app/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/pi/my_app /home/pi/my_app/lib/ini/src /home/pi/my_app/build /home/pi/my_app/build/lib/ini/src /home/pi/my_app/build/lib/ini/src/CMakeFiles/ini.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
make -f lib/ini/src/CMakeFiles/ini.dir/build.make lib/ini/src/CMakeFiles/ini.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'lib/ini/src/CMakeFiles/ini.dir/build'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/pi/my_app/build/CMakeFiles  18
[ 80%] Built target ini
make -f CMakeFiles/my_app.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/my_app.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
cd /home/pi/my_app/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/pi/my_app /home/pi/my_app /home/pi/my_app/build /home/pi/my_app/build /home/pi/my_app/build/CMakeFiles/my_app.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
make -f CMakeFiles/my_app.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/my_app.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/pi/my_app/build/CMakeFiles 19
[ 85%] Building C object CMakeFiles/my_app.dir/my_app.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -lm -I/home/pi/my_app/lib/bzle/include -I/home/pi/my_app/lib/ini/include -I/home/pi/my_app/lib/lib2/include -I/home/pi/my_app/lib/lib1/include    -o CMakeFiles/my_app.dir/my_app.c.o   -c /home/pi/my_app/my_app.c
In file included from /home/pi/my_app/my_app.c:53:0:
/home/pi/my_app/lib/lib1/include/lib1/lib1.h:2:18: fatal error: glib.h: No such file or directory
 #include <glib.h>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/my_app.dir/build.make:54: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/my_app.dir/my_app.c.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/my_app.dir/my_app.c.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:94: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/my_app.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/my_app.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

OK with `lib1.c`

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/my_app/build $ make VERBOSE=1
/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/pi/my_app -B/home/pi/my_app/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/pi/my_app/build/CMakeFiles /home/pi/my_app/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
make -f lib/bzle/src/CMakeFiles/bzle.dir/build.make lib/bzle/src/CMakeFiles/bzle.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
cd /home/pi/my_app/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/pi/my_app /home/pi/my_app/lib/bzle/src /home/pi/my_app/build /home/pi/my_app/build/lib/bzle/src /home/pi/my_app/build/lib/bzle/src/CMakeFiles/bzle.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
make -f lib/bzle/src/CMakeFiles/bzle.dir/build.make lib/bzle/src/CMakeFiles/bzle.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'lib/bzle/src/CMakeFiles/bzle.dir/build'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/pi/my_app/build/CMakeFiles  3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
[ 60%] Built target bzle
make -f lib/lib1/src/CMakeFiles/lib1.dir/build.make lib/lib1/src/CMakeFiles/lib1.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
cd /home/pi/my_app/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/pi/my_app /home/pi/my_app/lib/lib1/src /home/pi/my_app/build /home/pi/my_app/build/lib/lib1/src /home/pi/my_app/build/lib/lib1/src/CMakeFiles/lib1.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Dependee "../lib/lib1/include/lib1/other_beacon.h" is newer than depender "lib/lib1/src/CMakeFiles/lib1.dir/other_beacon.c.o".
Dependee "/home/pi/my_app/lib/lib1/src/other_beacon.c" is newer than depends file "/home/pi/my_app/build/lib/lib1/src/CMakeFiles/lib1.dir/depend.internal".
Clearing dependencies in "/home/pi/my_app/build/lib/lib1/src/CMakeFiles/lib1.dir/depend.make".
Scanning dependencies of target lib1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
make -f lib/lib1/src/CMakeFiles/lib1.dir/build.make lib/lib1/src/CMakeFiles/lib1.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/pi/my_app/build/CMakeFiles 1
[ 65%] Building C object lib/lib1/src/CMakeFiles/lib1.dir/other_beacon.c.o
cd /home/pi/my_app/build/lib/lib1/src && /usr/bin/cc   -I/home/pi/my_app/build/lib/lib1/src -I/home/pi/my_app/lib/lib1/src -I/home/pi/my_app/lib/lib1/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/glib-2.0/include -I/home/pi/my_app/lib/bzle/include    -o CMakeFiles/lib1.dir/other_beacon.c.o   -c /home/pi/my_app/lib/lib1/src/other_beacon.c
Linking C static library liblib1.a
cd /home/pi/my_app/build/lib/lib1/src && /usr/bin/cmake -P CMakeFiles/lib1.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
cd /home/pi/my_app/build/lib/lib1/src && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/lib1.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/ar cr liblib1.a  CMakeFiles/lib1.dir/other_beacon.c.o CMakeFiles/lib1.dir/ibeacon.c.o
/usr/bin/ranlib liblib1.a
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/pi/my_app/build/CMakeFiles  1 2
[ 70%] Built target lib1
make -f lib/lib2/src/CMakeFiles/lib2.dir/build.make lib/lib2/src/CMakeFiles/lib2.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
cd /home/pi/my_app/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/pi/my_app /home/pi/my_app/lib/lib2/src /home/pi/my_app/build /home/pi/my_app/build/lib/lib2/src /home/pi/my_app/build/lib/lib2/src/CMakeFiles/lib2.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
make -f lib/lib2/src/CMakeFiles/lib2.dir/build.make lib/lib2/src/CMakeFiles/lib2.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'lib/lib2/src/CMakeFiles/lib2.dir/build'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/pi/my_app/build/CMakeFiles  20
[ 75%] Built target lib2
make -f lib/ini/src/CMakeFiles/ini.dir/build.make lib/ini/src/CMakeFiles/ini.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
cd /home/pi/my_app/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/pi/my_app /home/pi/my_app/lib/ini/src /home/pi/my_app/build /home/pi/my_app/build/lib/ini/src /home/pi/my_app/build/lib/ini/src/CMakeFiles/ini.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
make -f lib/ini/src/CMakeFiles/ini.dir/build.make lib/ini/src/CMakeFiles/ini.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'lib/ini/src/CMakeFiles/ini.dir/build'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/pi/my_app/build/CMakeFiles  18
[ 80%] Built target ini
make -f CMakeFiles/my_app.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/my_app.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
cd /home/pi/my_app/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/pi/my_app /home/pi/my_app /home/pi/my_app/build /home/pi/my_app/build /home/pi/my_app/build/CMakeFiles/my_app.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Dependee "../lib/lib1/include/lib1/other_beacon.h" is newer than depends file "/home/pi/my_app/build/CMakeFiles/my_app.dir/depend.internal".
Clearing dependencies in "/home/pi/my_app/build/CMakeFiles/my_app.dir/depend.make".
Scanning dependencies of target my_app
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
make -f CMakeFiles/my_app.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/my_app.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/pi/my_app/build/CMakeFiles 19
[ 85%] Building C object CMakeFiles/my_app.dir/my_app.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -lm -I/home/pi/my_app/lib/bzle/include -I/home/pi/my_app/lib/ini/include -I/home/pi/my_app/lib/lib2/include -I/home/pi/my_app/lib/lib1/include    -o CMakeFiles/my_app.dir/my_app.c.o   -c /home/pi/my_app/my_app.c
Linking C executable my_app
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/my_app.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc  -lm    CMakeFiles/my_app.dir/my_app.c.o  -o my_app -rdynamic lib/bzle/src/libbzle.a lib/ini/src/libini.a lib/lib2/src/liblib2.a lib/lib1/src/liblib1.a lib/bzle/src/libbzle.a -lglib-2.0 
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/pi/my_app/build/CMakeFiles  19
[ 85%] Built target my_app
make -f lib/bzle/tools/CMakeFiles/hciconfig.dir/build.make lib/bzle/tools/CMakeFiles/hciconfig.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
cd /home/pi/my_app/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/pi/my_app /home/pi/my_app/lib/bzle/tools /home/pi/my_app/build /home/pi/my_app/build/lib/bzle/tools /home/pi/my_app/build/lib/bzle/tools/CMakeFiles/hciconfig.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Dependee "/home/pi/my_app/build/lib/bzle/tools/CMakeFiles/hciconfig.dir/DependInfo.cmake" is newer than depender "/home/pi/my_app/build/lib/bzle/tools/CMakeFiles/hciconfig.dir/depend.internal".
Dependee "/home/pi/my_app/build/lib/bzle/tools/CMakeFiles/CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake" is newer than depender "/home/pi/my_app/build/lib/bzle/tools/CMakeFiles/hciconfig.dir/depend.internal".
Scanning dependencies of target hciconfig
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
make -f lib/bzle/tools/CMakeFiles/hciconfig.dir/build.make lib/bzle/tools/CMakeFiles/hciconfig.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/pi/my_app/build/CMakeFiles 15
[ 90%] Building C object lib/bzle/tools/CMakeFiles/hciconfig.dir/csr.c.o
cd /home/pi/my_app/build/lib/bzle/tools && /usr/bin/cc   -Wall -I/home/pi/my_app/build/lib/bzle/tools -I/home/pi/my_app/lib/bzle/tools -I/home/pi/my_app/lib/bzle/include    -o CMakeFiles/hciconfig.dir/csr.c.o   -c /home/pi/my_app/lib/bzle/tools/csr.c
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/pi/my_app/build/CMakeFiles 16
[ 95%] Building C object lib/bzle/tools/CMakeFiles/hciconfig.dir/hciconfig.c.o
cd /home/pi/my_app/build/lib/bzle/tools && /usr/bin/cc   -Wall -I/home/pi/my_app/build/lib/bzle/tools -I/home/pi/my_app/lib/bzle/tools -I/home/pi/my_app/lib/bzle/include    -o CMakeFiles/hciconfig.dir/hciconfig.c.o   -c /home/pi/my_app/lib/bzle/tools/hciconfig.c
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/pi/my_app/build/CMakeFiles 17
[100%] Building C object lib/bzle/tools/CMakeFiles/hciconfig.dir/textfile.c.o
cd /home/pi/my_app/build/lib/bzle/tools && /usr/bin/cc   -Wall -I/home/pi/my_app/build/lib/bzle/tools -I/home/pi/my_app/lib/bzle/tools -I/home/pi/my_app/lib/bzle/include    -o CMakeFiles/hciconfig.dir/textfile.c.o   -c /home/pi/my_app/lib/bzle/tools/textfile.c
Linking C executable hciconfig
cd /home/pi/my_app/build/lib/bzle/tools && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/hciconfig.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc  -Wall    CMakeFiles/hciconfig.dir/csr.c.o CMakeFiles/hciconfig.dir/hciconfig.c.o CMakeFiles/hciconfig.dir/textfile.c.o  -o hciconfig -rdynamic ../src/libbzle.a -lglib-2.0 
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/pi/my_app/build/CMakeFiles  15 16 17
[100%] Built target hciconfig
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/my_app/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/pi/my_app/build/CMakeFiles 0
```

I have know ideas about this.
Could you please give me some advice?

Comment: is the compilation error coming from `lib1.c` or from another C file?

Comment: it come from lib1.h. I added more information to error log.

Comment: I understand it comes from `lib1.h` but while trying to compile which C file? `lib1.c` or another file?

Comment: add log from make VERBOSE=yes

Comment: @MysticOdin: while I am trying to compile `lib1.c` to static library.

Comment: @MysticOdin: Sorry for wrong information. While I am trying to compile another file which include `lib1.h`.

Comment: @arved: I added more log with `VERBOSE=yes`

Comment: i don't see my_app.c in your CMakeLists.txt

Comment: like initially suspected, your problem is that cmake list for another C-File does not include glib. it's generally not a very good idea to include a library header in the interface header, unless you're using types declared in that library header in your interfaces, so actually you should go with the first option rather than fixing the cmake list for the other C-File

Comment: @arved: I added more CMakeLists.txt for `my_app.c`
@MysticOdin: But `my_app.c` depends on `lib1`, and `lib1` depends on `glib`

Comment: exactly, `my_app.c` depends on `lib1`, and `lib1` depends on `glib`, if you include `glib` in the header for `lib1` you will have an extra dependency for my `my_app.c` that is not necessary, i.e. `my_app.c` will depend on `glib` as well as on `lib1`, and any other file for that matter that uses `lib1` who might not necessarily know or need `glib` will have to get it and link it even though he might have a statically linked version of `lib1` ready

Comment: also, in the future you may need to change `glib` to another library, why in that case will you force `my_app.c` to be recompiled?

Comment: as a rule of thumb, avoid including headers in headers as much as possible

Comment: @MysticOdin: I understood, but my `lib1.h` have some public function that have the `glib` objects. This is my problems.

Comment: Internally or in the definition of the interface in `lib1.h`?
Generally if you are able to compile without including `glib` in `lib1.h` then you don't have any reason to include `glib` in `lib1.h`

Comment: I have the problem if I do not including `glib` in `lib1.h`. In order to test `glib` with `lib1.c` I have to temporary delete all of my function name in `lib1.h`. That mean in other file, I can not call my function in `lib1.c`